# JavaFX Jar File Dependencies & Controlling Downloaded File Size

Tags: java, javafx, jar, javafx-8

With a JavaFX (web start) application, obviously you're downloading some jar files to the end user's desktop.  The more dependencies (like ControlsFX, Jackson, or even logging jars) you have the more you'll need to download, even if you're only using small parts of those dependency jars, right?

So is there any way to control or reduce the download size for a JavaFX application which uses such dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

Web start is designed to download all dependencies noted down in the JNLP-file.

If the license-situation is clear, you might want to take a look at the maven-shade-plugin (when using maven for building your files):

https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/includes-excludes.html

You can create some lib which only contains the classes you are using from the other dependencies.

For using gradle, you might want use shadowJar:

- https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow
- https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow
- http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/

Comment: Prefer a no-maven solution. Gradle is an option however.